# Windows Azure Service bus Subscription or not?

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

Our scenario is that we have 6 or more micro services each micro service is identified by an guid.

The different micro services knows about these guids and wants to communicate with the other micro services through queue's and because we are in azure we will use Windows Azure Service bus.

My question is, can I use the Filter without an subscription?
Each service are interested in their own messages which can be decided on one property but there can never be two subscribers on the same message.

What is the best thing to do here?

- Have one queue per micro service
- Use subscription with filters
- Use filters without subscriptions (if this is possible?)

Comment: Why avoid subscriptions?  Sounds like you just want to use a topic queue and add the guid as a property on the message.  The consumer would be able to use the filter within the subscription.

Comment: With queue you have competing consuming pattern with load leveling and load balacing but I think that isn't what you want. I think that the best solution is to use pub/sub pattern with topic/subscription and related filters on them.

Comment: Maybe it is filter I want or to have it routed. When a micro service receives a message it mostly wants to put a message back on the queue (this is kind of request response pattern through queues), can I read and write to the queue in one transaction even if it is a subscription?